# XML export large tally data

Tags: tally

```
<ENVELOPE>  
<HEADER>    
<TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST> 
</HEADER>   
<BODY>  
<EXPORTDATA>    
<REQUESTDESC>   
<STATICVARIABLES>   
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>  
<SVFROMDATE>" & TextBox2.Text & "</SVFROMDATE>  
<SVTODATE>" & TextBox1.Text & "</SVTODATE>  
</STATICVARIABLES>  
<REPORTNAME>Voucher Register</REPORTNAME>   
</REQUESTDESC>  
</EXPORTDATA>   
</BODY> 
</ENVELOPE>
```

Using above  XML request we are not able to fetch/ export large xml data from tally erp9.
Xml data is large(results in out of memory exceptions) even when specify company name , date interval etc.
 Is it posible to export specified number of voucher/Ledger  xml data , or   get the count of the voucher/Ledger present before exporting it to  XML.

Answer (score 1):

To get the count of all vouchers, you could do this:

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>FUNCTION</TYPE>
        <ID>$$NumItems</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <FUNCPARAMLIST>
                <PARAM>SplVoucherColl</PARAM>
            </FUNCPARAMLIST>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

From here on, you could either get the vouchers by:

1. Ledger
2. From and To Date
3. Voucher Type